# Why does 'find a file' and other items not appear when using 'group by' in a view?

Tags: view, menu

When I enable 'group by' in my view in order to group items by a certain column, I lose the 'find a file' feature along with some other menu bar options

using this:

[image: Group by feature in modify view page]

removes this:

[image: find a file and menu bar]

Is there any way to use group by and find a file in the same view?